# React Native FlatList and SectionList: How to fetch data on scroll up

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-sectionlist

In React Native's FlatList or SectionList, fetching paginated data when user scrolls to the end of the list is easy to implement with `onEndReached`.

However, if the `initialScrollIndex` is set, and user scrolls up, is there any way to fetch data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

liked the question :)

It can be done, ive just achieved it, do check it out on expo snack  https://snack.expo.dev/ZY7MlIX8M

```js
import React,{useState,useRef} from 'react';
import { SafeAreaView, View, FlatList, StyleSheet, Text, StatusBar } from 'react-native';

const DATA = [
  {
    id: 'bd7acbea-c1b1-46c2-aed5-3ad53abb28ba',
    title: 'First Item',
  },
  {
    id: '3ac68afc-c605-48d3-a4f8-fbd91aa97f63',
    title: 'Second Item',
  },
  {
    id: '58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-145571e29d72',
    title: 'Third Item',
  },
    {
    id: '58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-145571e29d72',
    title: 'Third Item2',
  },
    {
    id: '58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-145571e29d72',
    title: 'Third Item3',
  },
    {
    id: '58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-145571e29d72',
    title: 'Third Item4',
  },
    {
    id: '58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-145571e29d72',
    title: 'Third Item5',
  },
    {
    id: '58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-145571e29d72',
    title: 'Third Item6',
  },
   {
    id: '58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-145571e29d72',
    title: 'Third Item7',
  },
   {
    id: '58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-145571e29d72',
    title: 'Third Item7',
  },
   {
    id: '58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-145571e29d72',
    title: 'Third Item8',
  },
];

const Item = ({ title }) => (
  <View style={styles.item}>
    <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
  </View>
);

const App = () => {

  const [firstScroll,setFirst] = useState(null)

  const currrentY = useRef(null);


  const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
    <Item title={item.title} />
  );

  const onScroll = (event) =>{
    if(firstScroll === null){
      setFirst(event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y)
    }
    currrentY.current = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y

  }
  
  //here you will get when the user scrolled after initial index whether the user moved up, and then call api
   const onScrollENd = (event) => {
    console.log("false",event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y)
    if(event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y < firstScroll ){
      console.log("went up , call api here")
    }
  }


  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
      onScrollEndDrag={onScrollENd}
    
      onScroll={onScroll}
        data={DATA}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
        initialScrollIndex={6}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: StatusBar.currentHeight || 0,
  },
  item: {
    backgroundColor: '#f9c2ff',
    padding: 40,
    marginVertical: 8,
    marginHorizontal: 16,
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 40,
  },
});

export default App;
```

Hope it helps , feel free for doubts

Comment: @hayata if the answer helped you, do upvote too 